# ExpressionEngine V4 CMS Icons showed as squares, RichEditText box showed content as HTML and some Member Group setting showed as process bar

Tags: path, richtext

I am using ExpressionEngine Version 4, there are some issues with the CMS, please see the followings:

1. CMS icons are showing as squares.
2. RichEditText box doesn't show content as normal text, instead, it showed them as HTML code.
3. Some member group settings are not showing, only see a progress bar in there, and the bar doesn't seem to disappear.

I think this might be some issues with the path but I'm not able to find out why...

Please help.

Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is path issue as you think. You need to change path manually.

There is 2 ways to change the path in EE3 - EE4

1. Go to `Settings > URL and Path Settings` and change all necessary variables.
2. Install [Deeploy Helper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) module and change path from settings of this module. (This module is paid.)

Comment: Hi Harsh, after I redeployed the site, the icons are now fine, just the rich text and the other one doesn't work... I see that Deeploy Helper is $20, is there a way to edit the path manually?

Comment: Okay no worries. I have managed to change the paths.